# jpackage add files to installdir

Tags: java, wix, jpackage

I'm using jpackage from Java 15 to create an installer for my javafx application. Because one of the libraries requires some visual c++ dlls, I want to include them too. They should be placed into the directory where the main .exe and .ico resides.

I don't understand how to write an overrides.wxi to achieve that.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6
Here is all information I found about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to include your dll in your "input" folder and to change the library.path to include that folder via jpackage $APPDIR parameter like this:

```
jpackage --input input --java-options '-Djava.library.path=$APPDIR' ...
```

This is how I did it for my own project that needs dll and it works.

Comment: This is kind of a genius solution! Is $APPDIR already defined by jpackage?

Comment: Yes unfortunately it's not very well documented. I learned about this variable via their splash example.